# How to create a Fragment over the Viewpager in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Explanation:**
             I tried more but i failed to find the how to set the transparent fragment over the Viewpager. I am working in application. The requirement of my client is who will make a application like below url

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=munchery&hl=en

In above url application. In this application they were added more functionality like navigationDrawer, Tabs with viewpager and etc.

One thing is when i click on the actionBar Today's menu it's open something. I am not able to recognized to find what it actually open while i click on actionBar in the Munchery application.

I tried to implement but not implemented as same as the munchery application.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.millu.whatsappdemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Text view"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_up_arrow">
            </TextView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView action_text;
    public Toolbar toolbar;

    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    List<Fragment> fragmentList;
    List<String> tab_title;
    boolean flag=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        action_text = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.action_text);

        fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        tab_title = new ArrayList<>();

        tab_title.add("ONE");
        tab_title.add("TWO");
        fragmentList.add(new OneFragment());
        fragmentList.add(new TwoFragment());

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList, tab_title);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        action_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment=new ThirdFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if(!fragment.isHidden()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
                    flag=true;
                }
                else{
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
                    flag=false;
                }
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

In above code i set the flat onClick of the textview over the actionBar for hiding and showing the fragment. In my demo the problem is it show the tab when my third fragment is open and it does not hide.

Please help me to recognized what is it open on click of the actionBar?

Comment: I saw the app, its just opening dialogfragment or some custom dialog from above onClick of actionbartext.

Comment: I tried the dialog fragment but dialogFragment is hide the actionBar

Comment: Hey, Are you getting my point? It's hide the actionbar i want to hide only tabs

Comment: Yeah.Need to use something else might be.Let me just see.

Comment: Ohk if you will found tell me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as below: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text view"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/reltv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#80ffffff"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Do whatever you like it here."
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And your ManiActivity.java as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView action_text;
public Toolbar toolbar;

TabLayout tabs;
ViewPager viewPager;

List<Fragment> fragmentList;
List<String> tab_title;
boolean flag = false;

RelativeLayout reltv;
RelativeLayout reltv2;

boolean isShown = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    action_text = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.action_text);
    reltv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.reltv);
    reltv2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.reltv2);

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    tab_title = new ArrayList<>();

    tab_title.add("ONE");
    tab_title.add("TWO");
    fragmentList.add(new OneFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new TwoFragment());

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList, tab_title);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    action_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isShown) {
                isShown=true;
                reltv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                isShown=false;
                reltv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use some translucent or transparent colour for the android: background of parent's  attribute in  the fragment layout e.g DayFragment . This is the fragment you will inflate in the overlay FrameLayout.

For a smooth inflation of that fragment, you can use custom animation to make the transition smooth like in the Munchery app(uses slide from top animation)

```
protected void replaceFragment(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, boolean isAddToBackStack, boolean isAnimateTransition) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = fm.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            if(isAnimateTransition) {
                animateFragmentTransition(ft);
            }
            ft.replace(containerViewId, fragment, backStateName);
            if (isAddToBackStack) {
                ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            }
            ft.commit();
        }
    }


private void animateFragmentTransition(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.slide_in_from_top, R.anim.slide_out_to_top);
}


DayFragment fragment = DayFragment.newInstance(null);
        replaceFragment(R.id.container, fragment, false, true);
```

Alternitively, you can use ObjectAnimators to revael and hide views as you wish. For example:-

```
private void animate() {
        View viewToShiftOut = mNormalModelayoutContainer;
        View viewToShiftIn = mEditModelayoutContainer;
        ObjectAnimator outAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToShiftOut, "y", 0, -heightOfScreen);
        ObjectAnimator inAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToShiftIn, "y", heightOfScreen , 0);
        outAnim.setDuration(1000);
        inAnim.setDuration(1000);
        outAnim.start();
        inAnim.start();
    }
```